# Search for a digit within an component within a section with regex

Tags: java, regex

Given the string below:

```
G1:NMXPAKW63roBnMZ[RQ:1,2]-G2:Q9M7mPl9X4NG9Ry[QC:1,5]-G3:1Bd57mPl9X4NG9Ry[QC:1,5]
```

I have the following regex (the base of which is from a previous question):

```
 G2:(?:(?!-G)\S)*([^0-9]|^)1([^0-9]|$)
```

What I am trying to achieve is "get the section starting G2 and ending before the next section", in this case -G3, then "search back for the first digit".

This works, however I want to stop the search back when it hits the QC: part, currently if I replace 1 in the regex with 9, it matches the 9 in the hash component (Q9M7mPl9X4NG9Ry), which I don't want. In the section G2 I only want to look for a match in the QC:1,5 component.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `-G2:.*?\[(.*?)\]` will give you the part `QC:1,5`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WraMWH/1)

Comment: Thanks, I added to it to find digit 5, `-G2:.*?\[(.*?)\]*([^0-9]|^)5([^0-9]|$)` which works, however if I replace the 5 with a 9, it matches the 9 in the hash in the G3 section, it shouldn't keep looking past the -G.

Comment: @SteveFord I suspect I didn't understand what you're trying to do, if you want to search only inside: `Q9M7mPl9X4NG9Ry`, use: `-G2:(.*?)\[` otherwise, I'm not clear on which '9' you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will do: `(?:^|-)G2:(?:(?!-G).)*QC:(?:(?!-G).)*(?<!\d)(\d+)`

It works as follows:

- Locate section G2: `(?:^|-)G2:`
  This can be either the first section (input starts with `G2`), or a secondary section (matching `-G2`).
- Skip random text, but stop at next section: `(?:(?!-G).)*`
  This is basically a `.*`, but with a negative look-ahead to stop if the `.` would match the `-` in `-G`.
- Locate QC: `QC:`
- Skip random text, but stop at next section: `(?:(?!-G).)*`
- Match a whole number and capture it: `(?<!\d)(\d+)`

The second "skip text" will locate the end of the section, and will then backtrack from there until a number is found.

Since we're backtracking, we need the negative look-behind `(?<!\d)` to ensure the backtracking doesn't stop in the middle of a number.

See [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1g2SpI/1).

Comment: Great, and how do I search for a specific number, 50 or 1, just want to match one number but need to be able to specify which one. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is it: `(?:^|-)G2:(?:(?!-G).)*QC(?:(?!-G).)*([^0-9]|^)1([^0-9]|$)` and I can replace the 1 with the number I want to match.